# Losing the elemets/objects identity of same objects in parent window when renavigating from child window

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm able to navigate from parent window to child and vice versa. When i renavigated to parent window from child window I lost the  elements/objects identity of same objects in parent window. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Just find those elements again, each time you come back to the window.

Answer (score 0):

When u navigate from the parent window a stale element reference exception is thrown each time you interact with the previously found web elements.

In this case, although the replacement elements may look identical they are different; the driver has no way to determine that the replacements are actually the same or what's expected.

If the element has been replaced with an identical one, a useful strategy is to **look up the element again.**

To learn more, read [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp).